# Arreglo en Javascript de objetos diferentes devuelve el mismo objeto al acceder a todos sus elementos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un inconveniente manipulando un arreglo en Javascript que no he podido resolver ni explicar el comportamiento.

Inicialmente tengo 9 botones dentro de un div numerados del 1 al 9. Al hacer clic en el botón 5 los números de los botones alrededor deben girar en el sentido de las agujas del reloj.

Para realizar esto le agrego un evento (no puedo usar jQuery) manipulando directamente el DOM. Creo un arreglo y le agrego los 8 botones en el orden respectivo, clono el arreglo, al arreglo clonado le elimino el último elemento y se lo agrego al comienzo (así simulo el mover los elementos en sentido horario), a continuación le asigno el valor de los objetos del arreglo clonado al nuevo arreglo.

El inconveniente que ocurre es que le está asignando el número 4 a todos los valores que rodean al numero 5. Para verificar esto, en el código agregué dos códigos que, primero, me muestran el arreglo clonado permutado y los valores son los apropiados, pero en el segundo ciclo for, al volver a mostrar los valores del arreglo permutado son exactamente el mismo (el número 4) sin alterar el arreglo.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

```js
var button5 = document.getElementById("btn5");
button5.onclick = function() {
  var arrButtons = [];
  
  //Inicialmente el arreglo contendrá los objetos a
  //los botones representados por 1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn1"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn2"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn3"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn6"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn9"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn8"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn7"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn4"));
  
  //Clono el arreglo inicial.
  var newButtons = arrButtons.slice();
  
  //Permutar en el sentido de las agujas del reloj.
  newButtons.unshift(newButtons.pop());
  
  //Muestra el arreglo permutado correctamente
  //De 1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4 ahora es 4,1,2,3,6,9,8,7 en la primera iteración
  for (var i = 0; i < arrButtons.length; i++) {
    console.log(newButtons[i].innerHTML);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arrButtons.length; i++) {
    //Pero ahora solo muestra 4 para cada valor de newButtons[i] en la primera iteración
    console.log(newButtons[i].innerHTML)
    arrButtons[i].innerHTML = newButtons[i].innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
#btns {
  width: 75%
}
#btns .btn {
  width: 30%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btns">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" class="btn">3</button>
  <button id="btn4" class="btn">4</button>
  <button id="btn5" class="btn">5</button>
  <button id="btn6" class="btn">6</button>
  <button id="btn7" class="btn">7</button>
  <button id="btn8" class="btn">8</button>
  <button id="btn9" class="btn">9</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el orden del último bucle. Cuando lees el valor de un elemento ya ha sido actualizado en el anterior paso y no tiene el valor que crees que tiene (el antiguo) sino otro diferente (el nuevo que es 4).

Vamos a verlo paso a paso:

1. Asignas el valor del primer elemento (4) al segundo elemento (1)
2. Asignas el valor del segundo elemento (ahora 4) al tercer elemento (2)
3. Asignas el valor del tercer elemento (ahora 4) al cuarto elemento (3)
4. Asignas el valor del cuarto elemento (ahora 4) al quinto elemento (6)
5. ...

Y así con todos los elementos del array. Esto ocurre así porque aunque son dos arrays diferentes, los elementos son los mismos en ambos arrays (podrías verlo como referencias al mismo elemento). Así que modificando el innerHTML de un elemento en un array, estás cambiando el innerHTML del mismo elemento en el otro array (que está en otra posición)

Una posible solución sería recorrer el array en sentido inverso. De este modo no te encuentras con ese problema (aunque seguirías teniendo un problema con el primer/último elemento, por lo que necesitarías guardarlo en una variable y asignarlo al final, como hace falta una variable adicional cuando quieres intercambiar valores entre dos variables).

```js
var button5 = document.getElementById("btn5");
button5.onclick = function() {
  var arrButtons = [];
  //Inicialmente el arreglo contendrá los objetos a
  //los botones representados por 1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn1"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn2"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn3"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn6"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn9"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn8"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn7"));
  arrButtons.push(document.getElementById("btn4"));
  //Clono el arreglo inicial.
  var newButtons = arrButtons.slice();
  //Permutar en el sentido de las agujas del reloj.
  newButtons.unshift(newButtons.pop());

  // guarda el valor del último valor en una variable auxiliar
  var original = arrButtons[arrButtons.length -1 ].innerHTML;
  // recorre el array en sentido inverso para evitar que todos tengan el mismo valor
  for (var i = arrButtons.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(arrButtons[i].innerHTML + " = " + newButtons[i].innerHTML);
    arrButtons[i].innerHTML = newButtons[i].innerHTML;
  }
  // asigna la variable auxiliar al primer elemento
  arrButtons[0].innerHTML = original;
}
```

```css
#btns {
  width: 75%
}
#btns .btn {
  width: 30%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btns">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" class="btn">3</button>
  <button id="btn4" class="btn">4</button>
  <button id="btn5" class="btn">5</button>
  <button id="btn6" class="btn">6</button>
  <button id="btn7" class="btn">7</button>
  <button id="btn8" class="btn">8</button>
  <button id="btn9" class="btn">9</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te explico @AlvaroMontoro [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5259/25), tienes un problema con el orden en que procesas los elementos, a su explicación añadiré que la raíz del problema es que `slice` hace una copia superficial del arreglo y por lo tanto ambos arreglos tienen los mismos elementos, pero en un orden diferente.

Eso explica por que se sobre-escriben y por que procesarlos en el orden inverso funciona (con el parche del primero/ultimo elemento).

Ahora, para evitar el problema del primero o el ultimo elemento, te propongo este enfoque alternativo, que consiste en almacenar el contenido de los botones en un arreglo aparte según un orden preestablecido, luego "rotar" el orden de procesamiento y finalmente volver a establecer los valores en los elementos según el nuevo orden.

```js
var button5 = document.getElementById("btn5")
button5.onclick = function() {
  var order = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4]
      content = []

  order.forEach(function(ix) {
    content.push(document.getElementById("btn" + ix).innerHTML)
  })

  // sentido horario - cambiando solo el orden de procesamiento
  order.push(order.shift())

  // sentido anti-horario
  //order.unshift(order.pop())

  order.forEach(function(ix) {
    document.getElementById("btn" + ix).innerHTML = content.shift()
  })
}
```

```css
#btns {
  width: 75%
}
#btns .btn {
  width: 30%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btns">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" class="btn">3</button>
  <button id="btn4" class="btn">4</button>
  <button id="btn5" class="btn">5</button>
  <button id="btn6" class="btn">6</button>
  <button id="btn7" class="btn">7</button>
  <button id="btn8" class="btn">8</button>
  <button id="btn9" class="btn">9</button>
</div>
```